# Google cloud web service php compress

Tags: php, web-services, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I'd created my webservice to upload files, it's working fine, but would like to use compress gzip, this part it's not working, how can I upload my files with gzip ?

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$storageService = new Google_Service_Storage($client );
$bucket         = $this->bucketName;
$file_name      = md5(uniqid(rand(), true)) . '.' . $ext;
$file_content   = urldecode($myFile);

try {
    $postbody = array(
        'name' => $file_name,
        'data' => file_get_contents($file_content),
        'uploadType' => "resumable",
        'predefinedAcl' => 'publicRead',
    );
    $options = array('Content-Encoding' => 'gzip');

    $gsso = new Google_Service_Storage_StorageObject();
    $gsso->setName( $file_name );
    $gsso->setContentEncoding( "gzip" );

    $storageService->objects->insert( $bucket, $gsso, $postbody, $options );

} catch ( Exception $e){
    $result['error'] = json_decode($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Can you describe your problem a little more? What isn't working? Are there any error messages?

Comment: I mean, it's not showing an error, it doesn't compress the files keeping the same... :/